# Database Mail with SSL (like GMAIL SMTP) not working

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

Is anybody successful sending email via MS SQL Server Database Mail while secure connection is set ON in account settings?

I'm trying different SMTP servers with SSL to set up - like Gmail - and none of them is working. Yes, I have "unsafe access" ON in Google settings.

Seems to me like SSL in MS SQL Server is not working properly. When I try non-secure SMTP server it's working fine.

[image]

The error goes like this (don't know how / where to find more detailed description):

[image]

Please, don't ask me whether password it typed correctly - it is!

I've tryed **different** Gmail accounts on **different servers** - with the same unssuccesful result.

Comment: Everything with SSL works fine! Did you receive an error when you sent a test e-mail?

Comment: Yes, general error with no details - useless for troubleshooting. Are you successful with Gmail SMTP?

Comment: Please, post the error. Yes, I was able to setup e-mail using Gmail SMTP.

Comment: I did...thank you.

Comment: Have you tried port 465 instead of 587?

Comment: Yes, I did...with different error, simplier, more useless (Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server.)

Comment: And it's NOT just about Gmail. Other SMTP servers that force secure connection DOES NOT WORK too.

Comment: Can you log into your gmail account by using credentials you entered into SQL Server e-mail setup? Please, tell me you SQL Server version and edition. By the way the port 587 is correct.

Comment: Yes of course I can log into. I've tried different SQL versions but for simplicity lets talk about SQL 2017, Standard edition.

Comment: I tested with SQL Server 2017, Standard Edition. Everything works fine. Please, log again into your Google account and be sure that there are no sent items. The issue is not connected with SQL Server, rather with Google account. Try changing to outlook smtp-mail.outlook.com , port 587.

Comment: OK, the point is that it is working for you. This was my question.